# Activate extension via short cut key

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to open/initiate a google chrome extension via a short cut key. For example I would like to assign a short cut of, lets say, `CTRL + E` to open my extension and initiate it.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***UPDATE*** (5/24/2013): You can use the new [`chrome.commands`](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/commands.html) API, which provides built-in framework support for keyboard commands.

Original answer follows:

**Step 1:** Use a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) to bind a keypress listener to every page.

```
// in the content script, listen for Crtl+Shift+E (upper or lowercase)
document.documentElement.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    if((e.keyCode == 69 || e.keyCode == 101) && e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey) {
        // do something (step 2, below)
    }
}, true);
```

**Step 2:** For action outside of the content script, use [message passing](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to notify the background page that the shortcut key has been pressed and it should perform some action.

**Step 3**: The background page does some action. It's currently not possible (and will likely [never be possible](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30491)) to open a Browser Action popup programatically, but you could send an interactive [desktop notification](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html), open a new tab, or do a lot of other things.

[**EDIT:** Code edited to include Rob W.'s suggestions; see his important notes on security in the comment below.]

Comment: I'd bind the event to `document.documentElement`, with the third parameter ([useCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)) set to `true`. Elaboration: 1. `document.body` might be `null` for incomplete documents. 2. When `useCapture` is set to true, a page's `event.stopPropagation()` will not prevent your listener from being triggered. **Warning: It is possible to simulate this event in the page. Do not attach a potentially dangerous operation to the shortcut.**