# Is it Possible to invoke keyboard Function keys using Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on Chrome Extensions. I want to know that is it Possible to invoke keyboard Function keys using Chrome Extensions.

Thanks,
NVN.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Do you want to *simulate* function key presses on a page or *listen for* physical key presses from the user?  If you want want to procedurally trigger function key actions, you can't.  As Rob pointed out, scripted events only activate scripted event listeners, and do not trigger default behavior.

In order to detect function key presses, you need to bind your events to `keyup` -- **not** to `keypress`, which doesn't fire for several non-printable keystrokes, like function keys and arrow keys.

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 113) {
        // if F2 is pressed...
        // F1 is keycode 112, and it increments from there
    }
});
```

Some function keys do things already (F1 opens help, F5 refreshes, etc.).  If you have a good reason for preventing this behavior (e.g. you're making an immersive full-screen app like a VNC viewer that shouldn't exhibit normal browser behavior), you can use `preventDefault` on `keydown` to stop that potentially disruptive action:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 112) {
        // if F1 is pressed, don't open help
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

To see how to handle key presses for your Chrome extension, see my answer on [Activate extension via short cut key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10389452/710446); that should be exactly what you need for the rest.  Briefly:

- the code I gave above goes in a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) that gets added to each page
- the event handlers functions perform some action, either within the content script on the page or by [passing a message](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to the background page

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yes I want to simulate function keys from chrome extension. Ex. There is a button in extension page, when user clicks on button i want to simulate the function key actually. help me to do this.

Comment: @Nvn1509 That is **not possible**, for two reasons: 1. Chrome extensions cannot access the `chrome://extension/` URL. 2. Scripted key events can never be used to trigger default behaviour.

Comment: I'll delete this answer, then. Rob, if you like, repost your comment as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: Is there any way to display developer tools of browser with chrome extensions

Comment: Looks like no. See the answer to this [devtools feature request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112277): "*We only allow explicit devtools opening.*"

Comment: +1 for "In order to detect function key presses, you need to bind your events to keyup -- not to keypress"